# I want to make a chat app for android using app inventor app inventor

Tags: app-inventor

the application is a medical application for doctor and patient
When you log in as a patient, a list of available doctors appears online. You can call them or send a message to them.
When you log in as a doctor, a list of messages and missed contacts appears

Comment: What is stopping ***you*** from doing so??? Why are you ***announcing*** your plans?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please first [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I will create this application for you, you just need to wait

Comment: Answer is not useful for the community.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33183967)